# Fedora - MySQL Diskspace Problem and/or SELinux certificate problem

Tags: mysql, fedora, partition, selinux

similar questions have been asked before but they don't seem to work for me and I have a theory why that is (later in post).

Background: I have installed MySQL on my Fedora 31 to run a local server. Up to this point everything works as expected and I happily use my database. What I didn't consider is the fact that this database is using up some of my space, since the project I am working on is data-heavy, MySQL stopped running a query due to lack of space. I followed this Blog [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/05/move-mysql-directory/) to move the location of my directory in my main partition with plenty of space.

However, when restarting the server, it fails to do so. The error message given by `systemctl status mysqld.service` is: 
[image: The error screenshot]

From various sources I got the feeling that this has something to do with the SELinux context. As described in the blog post, I changed the type, which is as the original type. Upon inspection I realised that the user aspect of the context is different (system_u for /var/lib/mysql vs confined_u for /new/directory/in/home). I suspect it has something to do with the difference, given that the permission seems to be denied.

My Question now is: How do I fix this? Can I change the user without repercussions? If so, how? Another thought of mine while typing this - am I missing something, potentially I might have tried to move my database within the same partition without gaining extra space. To answer this question I would need to know if in a standard fedora installation /var and /home are located on different partitions. Answers to this? If this is the case - how can I allocate more space to my database so I don't have any more trouble running it? I still have 770 GB free in my /home partition, so that really shouldn't be an issue. See the screenshot below for my current partitions:
[image: The Partitions]

any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

**EDIT**: Output of ls -laZ 
[image: ls -laZ]
Is `semanage fcontext` the same as `chcon -R -t mysqld_db_t /data`? Because then I did `chcon -t mysqld_db_t /home`, `chcon -t mysqld_db_t /home/{username}` and `chcon -R -t mysqld_db_t /home/{username}/mysql_data`. I didnt do anything beyond this, because I just followed the blog post without looking left and right. Any suggestions based on this?

Comment: `fcontext` is changing what labels get to be the default for specific directories. If /home is ext[34] you can [reduce its size](https://serverfault.com/questions/420592/rebalance-centos-rhel-ext4-lvm-assignment/420632#420632) and grow the root. Or 17G is enough sufficient - delete the swap lv and use that for the root.

Comment: I just changed the size. This whole security context situation just confused (and scared) me. Thanks for your help! I wonder if you could just add the comment on how to change the sizes to your answer and then I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is permission denied so its not a space issue.

Try:
    systemctls edit mysqld.service

Create:

```
[Service]
ProtectHome=false
```

Then `systemctl start mysqld.service`

If that fails, look back at selinux. What `semanage fcontext` command was run? What `restorecon` command? What exactly is `ls -laZ {newdatadir}`?

Alternately to correct the space issue:

If /home is ext[34] you can [reduce its size](https://serverfault.com/questions/420592/rebalance-centos-rhel-ext4-lvm-assignment/420632#420632) (filesystem and logical volume) and grow the root logical volume and filesytem.

Or 17G is enough sufficient use the swap volume like:

```
swapoff /dev/fedora.../swap
lvremove fedora.../swap
lvextend fedora.../root -L +17G
resize2fs /
in /etc/fstab remove swap entry (or replace with 1-2G file based swap)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I just upadated my post with the screenshot and some additional information!

Comment: The space issue was my original issue why I tried to move the directory. If now someone comes along and tells me how to fix my space issue without moving the directory, I would be very happy to do that instead. Sorry if that wasnt clear